# Azure ARM Template variable conditions

Tags: json, azure

I have a arm template that i'm trying to apply regional conditions to. Like if the Region variable equals EUW then use variable westeurope. Can this be done as an array in the parameters or should this be a variable array with if statements?

I have seen on other threads that ARM templates are really more of an if/else statement instead of if/ifelse/else.

Classic example:

```
"availabilitySet": "[if(equals(parameters('production'), 'Yes'), variables('availabilitySetId'), json('null'))]",
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
"parameters": {
    "Region": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "USSC",
        "allowedValues": [
            "AIE",
            "BRS",
            "EUW",
            "USSC"
        ],
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Select Region"
        }
    }
},

"variables": {
    "regionReference": {
        "eastasia": "[if(equals(parameters('Region'), 'AIE')],
        "brazilsouth": "[if(equals(parameters('Region'), 'BRS')],
        "westeurope": "[if(equals(parameters('Region'), 'EUW')],
        "southcentral": "[if(equals(parameters('Region'), 'USSC')],
    }
}
```

Please forgive me for butchering that in advance. I also considered condition statements, but haven't gotten that to work either.

Comment: what are you after exactly? because right now you are just setting one value to true and others to false.

Comment: Essentially, i'm just trying to translate these region abbreviations to the actual region azure can interpret. Doesn't matter to me if its the abbreviation to the region or region to the abbreviation. At the moment, the template is not able to delineate which to use. I'm hoping to get to a point where the region can be selected and deployed with naming standards intact.

Comment: yeah, my answer would be a way to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just do this:

```
"regionReference": {
    "AIE": "eastasia",
    "BRS": "brazilsouth",
    "EUW": "westeurope",
    "USSC": "southcentral"
}
```

and then you can reference which region you've chosen:

```
"location": "[variables('regionReference')[parameters('Region')])]"
```

Although, I dont see why are you making your life harder in here for no real reason

Comment: I can't speak for the original poster but we ran into this before when using the region abbreviation as part of the resource name so that is one potential use if this. For instance wapp-appname-euw and wapp-appname-aie where the name is determined based on the region of the resource group being deployed to and/or parameter passed into it to help with high availability resources adhering to a common naming standard.

Comment: Using "location": "[variables('regionReference').[parameters('Region')]]", give an error on deployment. ```Deployment template language expression evaluation failed: 'Unable to parse language expression 'variables('regionReference').[parameters('Region')]': expected token 'Identifier' and actual 'LeftSquareBracket'.'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details. (Code: InvalidTemplate)```

Comment: sorry, its a typo, try without the `.` -..-

Comment: I removed that comment, meant to agree and say it worked without the dot. Saved me from having to make 30 different templates. Thank you again.